# How can I create a new content type based on an attached format

Tags: views, 7, nodes

I'm creating an intranet company portal website and the HR department requests I create a new Content Type/View for employee records. They sent me a document based on the format they would like. I was hoping to get some input on the easiest way of creating this content type/View

I uploaded the format to the following snapshot:
[image: snap]

My questions are as follows

1. How can I format the Expiration Date field to align to the right of it's specific corresponding field
2. When adding new content with the HR content type, is it possible for the user to click "Add new Incident/Disciplinary/Recognition field"? For example, start with one field for each but if the employee has earned more rewards etc they can add a new field?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
Place each expiration field above the corresponding other field and then add the following CSS rules to your theme:

```
form.node-form .field-name-field-product-EXPIRATION-DATE {
position:absolute;
right:0;
width:200px;
}
```

On the content creation pages, this will move the expiration field to the top right of the field below.

2) Yes, users can add an unlimited amount of values to each field. To enable this go to the desired field in your content type and edit it. There look for "Number of values" near the bottom of the page. Choose the desired amount. Suppose you choose 5, the user creating the content can add up to 5 values for this one field. I hope this works out for you.

Comment: You are most welcome ^^

Comment: Would you mind clicking the green check mark on the left? This marks my answer as a good one and gives me a little bit more reputation and privileges on this stack exchange. You can click the up arrow aswell! ;)

Comment: Done! I'm new to Drupal Stack Exchange. Again thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)